# Why does rxjs complain about items defined as Type[] when it comes to operators?

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6

I am thinking I might have made a fundamental mistake when typing out our endpoints.

https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/map.html
Shows examples of an array of objects that seem to work fine with the operators in their examples.

```
  this.taskService.getResponsibleParties().pipe(
        takeUntil(this.onDestroy$),
        map(({responPartyDesc}) => responPartyDesc)
    ).subscribe(responsibleParties => {
        this.responsableParties = responsibleParties;
    });
```

getResponsibleParties is defined with a return value below

```
    getResponsibleParties(): Observable<Array<ResponsibleParty>>
```

Most items that come back from the backend will be an Array of some type interface. Why in this example does Rxjs yells about

```
     map(({responPartyDesc}) => responPartyDesc)
```

ResponsibleParty[] has no property 'responPartyDesc'

Isn't this exactly the same thing that the docs lays out as working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [learn-rxjs map example](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/map.html), the observable emits a single object at a time:

```
const source: Observable<{ name: string, age: number }> = from([
  { name: 'Joe', age: 30 },
  { name: 'Frank', age: 20 },
  { name: 'Ryan', age: 50 }
]);
```

Therefore, the `map` operator callback can declare the parameter as an object with a `name` property:

```
const example = source.pipe(map(({ name }) => name));
```

---

In your case, the observable emits an array (instead of one item at a time), and the array itself does not have the `responPartyDesc` property. If you want to modify the array to keep only the `responPartyDesc` property, you can call the `Array.map()` method in the `map` operator, using one of these two syntaxes:

```
map((values: Array<ResponsibleParty>) => values.map(x => x.responPartyDesc))

map((values: Array<{ responsPartyDesc }>) => values.map(x => x.responPartyDesc))
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-vu967a?file=index.ts) for a demo.

Comment: Would that mean that our backend is not sending data in best format to work as observables?

Comment: Not really. You just have to know what kind of data you are working with, so that you can adapt the code samples that you find on Angular web sites.